# ServiceStack SOAP support extension

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

will ServiceStack extends support for SOAP service in .NET 6?
We’ve seen from documentation that SoapFormat plug-in requires .NET Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOAP Support requires full WCF support which has no plans on being made available on .NET 6 so SOAP Support will be limited to .NET Framework.

We recommend adopting [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference) which enables a much faster & cleaner superior end-to-end development model for all its [9 supported languages](https://servicestack.net/service-reference).